# Spring roo: Cannot update user data which was inserted by PhpMyAdmin

Tags: hibernate, spring-roo

I use spring roo to build a CMS webapp.

This app of course, has user management function.

My problem is if I use PhpMyAdmin to insert user information into database and then goto my app to modified thoes information, the error orcur. (If I insert user info by app and edit by app, it works fine)

Can anyone of you explain to me why it happend and how to resolve it?

Thank you very much.

Addition info: this error orcur only by user table, another table (such as news or product) has no problem.
Below is a few of my code.

EndUser.java (Entity)

```
public class EndUser {

    @NotNull
    @Size(min = 1, max = 20)
    @Column(name = "user_id", unique = true, nullable = false)
    private String userId;

    @Column(name = "user_name")
    private String name;

    @NotNull
    @Size(min = 1, max = 40)
    @Column(name = "password", nullable = false)
    private String password;

    @Column(name = "first_name")
    private String firstName;

    @Column(name = "last_name")
    private String lastName;

    @Column(name = "gender")
    private Integer gender;

    @Column(name = "email")
    private String email;

    @Column(name = "last_login")
    @DateTimeFormat(style = "M-")
    private Date lastLogin;

    @Column(name = "created_date")
    @DateTimeFormat(style = "M-")
    private Date createdDate;

    @Column(name = "date_of_birth")
    @DateTimeFormat(style = "M-")
    private Date dateOfBirth;

    @NotNull
    @Column(name = "role")
    private String role;

    @Column(name = "is_deleted")
    private Boolean isDeleted;
}
```

EndUserController.java

```
@PreAuthorize("hasRole('ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN')")
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.PUT, produces = "text/html")
public String update(@Valid EndUser endUser, BindingResult bindingResult, Model uiModel, HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest) {
    if (bindingResult.hasErrors()) {
        populateEditForm(uiModel, endUser);
        return "admin/user/update";
    }

    endUser.setIsDeleted(false);

    uiModel.asMap().clear();
    endUser.merge();
    return "redirect:/admin/user/" + encodeUrlPathSegment(endUser.getId().toString(), httpServletRequest);
}
```

If I update user info which was inserted by PhpMyAdmin, the error orcur

```
2013-05-08 20:10:58,741 [http-8080-7] DEBUG org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager - Found thread-bound EntityManager [org.hibernate.ejb.EntityManagerImpl@165f5a4] for JPA transaction
2013-05-08 20:10:58,741 [http-8080-7] DEBUG org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager - Creating new transaction with name [vn.a2s.lib.db.model.EndUser.merge]: PROPAGATION_REQUIRED,ISOLATION_DEFAULT; ''
2013-05-08 20:10:58,741 [http-8080-7] DEBUG org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager - Not exposing JPA transaction [org.hibernate.ejb.EntityManagerImpl@165f5a4] as JDBC transaction because JpaDialect [org.springframework.orm.jpa.DefaultJpaDialect@157f3a4] does not support JDBC Connection retrieval
2013-05-08 20:10:58,743 [http-8080-7] DEBUG org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata - Processing injected method of bean 'vn.a2s.lib.db.model.EndUser': PersistenceElement for transient javax.persistence.EntityManager vn.a2s.lib.db.model.EndUser.entityManager
2013-05-08 20:10:58,743 [http-8080-7] DEBUG org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'entityManagerFactory'
2013-05-08 20:10:58,752 [http-8080-7] ERROR org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper - Duplicate entry 'nghi' for key 'user_id'
2013-05-08 20:10:58,752 [http-8080-7] ERROR org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper - Duplicate entry 'nghi' for key 'user_id'
2013-05-08 20:10:58,752 [http-8080-7] DEBUG org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager - Initiating transaction rollback
2013-05-08 20:10:58,752 [http-8080-7] DEBUG org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager - Rolling back JPA transaction on EntityManager [org.hibernate.ejb.EntityManagerImpl@165f5a4]
2013-05-08 20:10:58,753 [http-8080-7] DEBUG org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager - Not closing pre-bound JPA EntityManager after transaction
2013-05-08 20:10:58,754 [http-8080-7] DEBUG org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver - Resolving exception from handler [public java.lang.String vn.a2s.sparepart.web.admin.EndUserController.update(vn.a2s.lib.db.model.EndUser,org.springframework.validation.BindingResult,org.springframework.ui.Model,javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest)]: org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaSystemException: org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: Duplicate entry 'nghi' for key 'user_id'; nested exception is javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: Duplicate entry 'nghi' for key 'user_id'
2013-05-08 20:10:58,754 [http-8080-7] DEBUG org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.ResponseStatusExceptionResolver - Resolving exception from handler [public java.lang.String vn.a2s.sparepart.web.admin.EndUserController.update(vn.a2s.lib.db.model.EndUser,org.springframework.validation.BindingResult,org.springframework.ui.Model,javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest)]: org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaSystemException: org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: Duplicate entry 'nghi' for key 'user_id'; nested exception is javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: Duplicate entry 'nghi' for key 'user_id'
2013-05-08 20:10:58,754 [http-8080-7] DEBUG org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.support.DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver - Resolving exception from handler [public java.lang.String vn.a2s.sparepart.web.admin.EndUserController.update(vn.a2s.lib.db.model.EndUser,org.springframework.validation.BindingResult,org.springframework.ui.Model,javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest)]: org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaSystemException: org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: Duplicate entry 'nghi' for key 'user_id'; nested exception is javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: Duplicate entry 'nghi' for key 'user_id'
2013-05-08 20:10:58,754 [http-8080-7] DEBUG org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.SimpleMappingExceptionResolver - Resolving exception from handler [public java.lang.String vn.a2s.sparepart.web.admin.EndUserController.update(vn.a2s.lib.db.model.EndUser,org.springframework.validation.BindingResult,org.springframework.ui.Model,javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest)]: org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaSystemException: org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: Duplicate entry 'nghi' for key 'user_id'; nested exception is javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: Duplicate entry 'nghi' for key 'user_id'
2013-05-08 20:10:58,754 [http-8080-7] DEBUG org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.SimpleMappingExceptionResolver - Resolving to view 'dataAccessFailure' for exception of type [org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaSystemException], based on exception mapping [.DataAccessException]
2013-05-08 20:10:58,754 [http-8080-7] DEBUG org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.SimpleMappingExceptionResolver - Exposing Exception as model attribute 'exception'
2013-05-08 20:10:58,754 [http-8080-7] DEBUG org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet - Handler execution resulted in exception - forwarding to resolved error view: ModelAndView: reference to view with name 'dataAccessFailure'; model is {exception=org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaSystemException: org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: Duplicate entry 'nghi' for key 'user_id'; nested exception is javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: Duplicate entry 'nghi' for key 'user_id'}
org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaSystemException: org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: Duplicate entry 'nghi' for key 'user_id'; nested exception is javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: Duplicate entry 'nghi' for key 'user_id'
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryUtils.convertJpaAccessExceptionIfPossible(EntityManagerFactoryUtils.java:318)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.aspectj.JpaExceptionTranslatorAspect.ajc$afterThrowing$org_springframework_orm_jpa_aspectj_JpaExceptionTranslatorAspect$1$18a1ac9(JpaExceptionTranslatorAspect.aj:15)
    at vn.a2s.lib.db.model.EndUser_Roo_Jpa_ActiveRecord.ajc$interMethod$vn_a2s_lib_db_model_EndUser_Roo_Jpa_ActiveRecord$vn_a2s_lib_db_model_EndUser$merge(EndUser_Roo_Jpa_ActiveRecord.aj:72)
    at vn.a2s.lib.db.model.EndUser.merge(EndUser.java:1)
    at vn.a2s.lib.db.model.EndUser_Roo_Jpa_ActiveRecord.ajc$interMethodDispatch1$vn_a2s_lib_db_model_EndUser_Roo_Jpa_ActiveRecord$vn_a2s_lib_db_model_EndUser$merge(EndUser_Roo_Jpa_ActiveRecord.aj)
    at vn.a2s.sparepart.web.admin.EndUserController.update(EndUserController.java:87)
    at vn.a2s.sparepart.web.admin.EndUserController$$FastClassByCGLIB$$ed0ea343.invoke(<generated>)
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:204)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:698)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:150)
    at org.springframework.security.access.intercept.aopalliance.MethodSecurityInterceptor.invoke(MethodSecurityInterceptor.java:61)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:631)
    at vn.a2s.sparepart.web.admin.EndUserController$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$48aaf78c.update(<generated>)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:219)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:132)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:104)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandleMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:746)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:687)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:80)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:925)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:856)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:915)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPut(FrameworkServlet.java:833)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:640)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:796)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.OpenEntityManagerInViewFilter.doFilterInternal(OpenEntityManagerInViewFilter.java:180)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:311)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:116)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:83)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:323)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:113)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:323)
    at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:101)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:323)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:113)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:323)
    at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:54)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:323)
    at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:45)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:323)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(BasicAuthenticationFilter.java:150)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:323)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:182)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:323)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:105)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:323)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:87)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:323)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:173)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:346)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:259)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:74)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:88)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:298)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:852)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:588)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:489)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: is there a version column/field on the table/object?

Comment: Yes, version field is managed in EndUser_Roo_Entity.aj

Answer (score 1):

Hibernate, out of the box, is setup in such a way that it does not support modifying the tables directly.  This is because Hibernate is caching the Entities between reads/writes.  If you request the same object over and over, Hibernate, if it's doing it's job correctly, should be reading the object once, doing all updates to the cache, and only writing the object when the cache expires.

If you modify the DB behind Hibernate, then the items in the Cache do not match what is in the DB.  There is a way to turn this off in Hibernate, but it has performance implications.  Unfortunately, it's been quite some time since I had to do this in Hibernate, so how you actually go about doing this I am not 100% sure.  You may have to spend some time googling for it.

Comment: I cannot explain why it's working to do direct inserts with one table and not the other.  I can say that Hibernate, by default, expects to control the data in the database.  I know this because we ran into the same issues with Hibernate connected to a DB2 database that was being inserted from another application.  I remember having to configure Hibernate to turn off the 2nd level cache, as it tended to barf on itself when something changed underneath it.  I believe, when configured to allow outside inserts, Hibernate uses the version column to detect change collisions.

Comment: Nice explaination. Thank you for your suggess. I will try to turn off the 2nd level cache and report the result soon.

Comment: This is my realy ugly fault. I created data in excel file and in sheet news (or product) I have already put an integer value to column version but in sheet user, the 'version' column have no value, therefor hibernate will try to persist my object instead of update it.